# region monitoring doesn't call didExitRegion unless conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I'm building an iOS 8 app that uses GeoFencing. I'm having some problems that I will explain later. But first, this is how I create a region and monitor it:

**Variables in header file:**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

**viewDidLoad:**

```
    // Initialize locationManager
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    // Set the delegate
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
```

Creating a region:

```
- (CLRegion*)mapDictionaryToRegion:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
NSString *title = [dictionary valueForKey:@"title"];

CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
CLLocationDegrees longitude =[[dictionary valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

CLLocationDistance regionRadius = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"radius"] doubleValue];

return [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centerCoordinate
                                               radius:regionRadius
                                           identifier:title];
}
```

Start monitoring it:

```
-(void)startMonitoringForDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
// Start monitoring for the supplied data
CLRegion *region = [self mapDictionaryToRegion:dictionary];
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];

}
```

**Listening for region crossing:**

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
NSLog(@"didEnterRegion");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
NSLog(@"exited region");
}
```

**I've remembered these keys in my target info:**

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

**Problem:**

Sometimes when I enter a region, it works flawless. Both didEnterRegion and didExitRegion is called like expected. But it appears as if I add the region while inside it, and then exit - it won't call didExitRegion. Only if it calls didEnterRegion first.

**What I'm asking:**

Could someone please explain the "rules" for region monitoring and how the device manages it, reports it, wakes app, etc? Also, I read in the documentation that I shouldn't expect updates more frequently than every 5 minutes. (This thing I'm making to practice calculates how long you've spent inside a region) - what if the user enters then exists quickly - then didExitRegion will never be called until I enter again?

Thanks!
Erik

Comment: Hi @Erik, did you come up with a solution for this?

Comment: @QuentinMalgaud Hi! I didn't find a specific problem or solution, but after a lot of tweaking and changing of code, I got it to work. I re-did my app recently to have a new design and way cleaner code, and it worked flawless even if I added a region while inside it. Just go through every step and make sure you've done everything. There might be something hidden in the accuracy and filter specifications though - take a look at those perhaps

Answer (score 0):

You must call [requestState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423804-requeststate) immediately when calling `startMonitoringForRegion`